# Sum 1 to N, printing every sum along the way in a new row (recursion)

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a basic program down that sums 1 to N.

However, I need to print *every* line of sums leading up to 'N'.

ex: input -> 3

1 = 1

1 + 2 = 3

1 + 2 + 3 = 6

I need to do this through recursion without using any loops in the code.

Any help appreciated. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int sumToN(int n, int row);

int input;

int main() 
{
    cout << "Sum to: ";
    cin >> input;
    cout << sumToN(input, 1);
}

int sumToN(int n, int row)
{

    if (row==n) // BASE CASE
    {
        cout << row << " = ";
        return row;
    }


    else // RECURSIVE CASE
    {
        cout << row << " + ";
        return (row + sumToN(n, row+1));
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See this :

```
int sumToN(int n, int row);

void out(int n);

int input;

int main() 
{
    cout << "Sum to: \n";
    cin >> input;
    out(1);

}

void out(int n)
{
    if( n > input) return;
    cout << sumToN(n, 1)<<"\n";
    out(n+1);
}
int sumToN(int n, int row)
{

    if (row==n) // BASE CASE
    {
        cout << row << " = ";
        return row;
    }


    else // RECURSIVE CASE
    {
        cout << row << " + ";        
         return (row + sumToN(n, row+1));
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Edited: for no loop :)

Comment: what's the reason of asking _Sum up to:_ in the `main()` routine, if you are never using that, and then do a `out(1);` instead?

Comment: @LuisColorado : 'Out' is a recursive call  ( loop not allowed - OP) that also calls 'sum2N' .

Comment: yes, but you call it as `Out(1)` and not as `Out(input)` which should be.  That way, as I follow the program, you are going to always print the sums from 1 to 1, and no more.  I think this is a mistake you did when you edited your code, or a quick cut and paste from your tests.... I know it is recursive, but you need to use the value of input somewhere and no reference to it anywhere in your code.

Comment: OP has used 'input' as global variable, calling Out(1), n will be assigned as 1 initially, and it will increment till it exceeds 'input'. It works.

Comment: **but you never use the value of  `input` variable in the program, so how do you know when to stop printing sums (or the limit of those) if you never use the value of that variable?**

Comment: 'input' is used as boundary condition in out()

Comment: your listing doesn't even compile, because it is not complete (lacks header files) so *HOW CAN IT WORK?*

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like storing the sum like 1+2.. In a string and keep appending the new number on each call and also output the new sum in each call after the string

Comment: Save the n the current result and the current iterration

Answer (score 1):

Use a internal value `prefix_val` and `prefix_str` to store the prefix recursive result. Then we can output the whole recursive workflow.

```
int sumToN(int n, int row, int prefix_val, const std::string& prefix_str);

int main()
{
    // Meanwhile you should void using global variables.
    int input;    
    cout << "Sum to: ";
    cin >> input;
    sumToN(input, 1, 0, "");
}

int sumToN(int n, int row, int prefix_val, const std::string& prefix_str)
{
    string gap;
    if (prefix_val == 0) {
        gap = "";
    } else {
        gap = " + ";
    }

    cout << prefix_str << gap << row << " = " << prefix_val + row << std::endl;
    if (row == n) // recursive end
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return sumToN(n, row + 1, row + prefix_val, prefix_str + gap + std::to_string(row));
}
```

**DEMO OUTPUT**

```
Sum to: 10
1 = 1
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 36
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 45
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55
```

Answer (score 0):

With loops you can do something like that:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void displayToN(const int last) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<last; sum += i, i++)
        cout << i << " + ";
    cout << last << " = " << (sum + last) << endl;
}

void sumToN(const int curr, const int last) {
    for (int i=curr; i<=last; i++)
        displayToN(i);
}

int main() {
    int input;
    cout << "Sum to: ";
    cin >> input;
    sumToN(1, input);
}
```

But with your limits, you have to emulate for loops with recursion like that:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void displayToN(const int curr, const int last, const int sum = 0) {
    if (curr < last) {
        cout << curr << " + ";
        displayToN(curr + 1, last, sum + curr);
    } else {
        cout << curr << " = " << (sum + curr) << endl;
    }
}

void sumToN(const int curr, const int last) {
    if (curr <= last) {
        displayToN(1, curr);
        sumToN(curr + 1, last);
    }
}

int main() {
    int input;
    cout << "Sum to: ";
    cin >> input;
    sumToN(1, input);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This works

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int input;


int sumToN(int n, int row)
{

    if (row==n) // BASE CASE
    {
        cout << row << " = ";
        //cout<< row<<endl;
        return row;
    }


    else // RECURSIVE CASE
    {
        cout << row << " + ";
        return (row + sumToN(n, row+1));
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void caller(int n,int current){
    if(current==n){
        cout<<sumToN(n,1)<<endl;
    }
    else{

        cout<<sumToN(current,1)<<endl;
        caller(n,current+1);
    }

}

int main() 
{
    cout << "Sum to: "<<endl;
    cin >> input;
    caller(input, 1);

}
```

Output

```
Sum to:3
1 = 1
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
```

Comment: @LuisColorado Removed loops.

Comment: @Keval, removed comment :)